# Objective c JSON print key from every table row

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

So i made a little database for a cocos2d objective c game I´m working on.
I made a mysql database and parsed the data with php and JSON to a NSDctionary.
My NSDictionary currently looks like this:

```
 {
    users =     (
                {
            country = Austria;
            deaths = 0;
            gender = 0;
            id = 1;
            "time_played" = 0;
            username = flo;
        },
                {
            country = austria;
            deaths = 42;
            gender = 0;
            id = 5;
            "time_played" = 1337;
            username = heinrich;
        }
    );
}
```

How can I output the username from every user?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your JSON is deserialized into the variable `JSON` :

```
for (NSDictionary *user in (NSArray*)[JSON objectForKey:@"users"]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [user objectForKey:@"username"]);
}
```

*Note: the typecast to NSArray isn't required, but included for readability*